A sequence $(x^k) \subset l^p$ with $|x^k_n| \leq a_n$ for $(a_n)\in l^p$ has a convergent subsequence
I am trying to do the following exercise:
Let $1 \leq p < \infty$, $(a_n)\in l^p$, and $(x^k)\subset l^p$ a sequence such that
$$
|x^k_n| \leq a_n \qquad \forall k=1,2,3,4, \ldots 
$$
Then $(x^k)$ has a convergent subsequence.
I assume that the $l^q$-space might be involved, perhaps one could use that there are functionals $\phi_k$ such that $\phi_k(x^k) = x^k$, but I do not know how.
I do not know how to approach the problem. Any hint with how to involve subsequences is appreciated.

Thank you @Ryszard, I didn't pay enough attention☺️ I retract and delete my comment.

The question has some answers. I propose a different approach based on compact operators. Consider the operator $T:\ell^\infty \to \ell^p$ defined by $(Tx)_k=a_kx_k.$  Let $T_n:\ell^\infty \to \ell^p$ act as follows$$(T_nx)_k=\begin{cases}a_kx_k & 1\le k\le n\\ 0 & k>n\end{cases}$$ Then $$\|T_n-T\|=\left (\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k^p\right )^{1/p}\underset{n}{\longrightarrow}0$$ Thus $T$ is a compact operator as the norm limit of finite dimensional operators. Observe that the family of sequences in OP belong to $T(B_1),$ where $B_1$ denotes the unit ball in $ \ell^\infty.$ As $T(B_1)$ is relatively compact in $\ell^p$ the conclusion follows.
